# I want to write a shell script to authorize the user but doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell

I call the hello.sh in my .bash_profile.
I try to exit when the user enters a wrong name, but it doesn't work. I think this is because the profile is read before the shell actually runs, so the exit will not affect the shell running. How to reach my goal?

The code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What's you name?"
read name
if [ $name = "Frank" ]
then
  echo 'Hello' $name 
  echo 'So happy to see you'
  echo 'Happy coding :)'
else
  echo 'You are not the right user.'
  echo `exit`
fi
```

Comment: you have `echo \`exit\`` (backtics around `exit`), why not just plain `exit`? (Can't remember now, but running the "fixed" version may close you terminal window. Be prepared or run in a separate window). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter It will print the text but still cannot exit the current terminal window.

Comment: How are you calling it?   If you simply have "hello.sh" in your profile, it'll start a new shell for it.  Have you tried ". hello.sh" ?   (note the space after the ".").  That'll run that file in the existing shell.

Comment: @racraman It works! Thank you.

Comment: Are you using `echo exit` now? There should be nothing but `exit` on that line.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I didn't specify which shell should the script run in. After add ". hello.sh" it works now. I also correct the "echo exit" to "exit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a shell file directly implicitly starts and executes in a new shell.  That means the exit statement is only exiting from the subshell.

Calling with ". hello.sh" will execute hello.sh in the existing shell, so the exit statement will terminate that shell and the window with it.